# Finding phase and period of an interfering signal (and possibly subtracting it)

Tags: noise

[image]
The signal in question consists of small quasi-periodic "packets" having a certain shape (outlined with green; gets closer to Gaussian as there are more peaks per packet). The problem is that there is a periodic signal (marked with red dots) which, when overlapping with a "packet", spoils its shape and thus complicates detection of these packets. The period is $1 + \epsilon$, with $\epsilon \sim 0.0005$ (can probably slightly differ case-to-case). The periodic signal goes across the whole range of detection (think from 100 to 3000), unlike the quasi-periodic signals (which span over a range of 2-3). There are then like ~3000 of peaks stemming from this signal; also, 3000 * 0.0005 = 1.5 (so, the position of peaks shifts over the detection range). The values coming from the interfering signal differ over the range of detection (by a factor of ~10), but seem to change quite slowly.

My questions would be:

- Is there a way to automatically detect positions of these peaks without any domain knowledge, purely "mathematically"? Or, in other words, the phase and period of these?
- Is there a way to remove this periodic signal? (For the cases of overlapping with the "packets", which is the most important, "removing" would mean subtracting the interfering signal and leaving as much of the original packet as possible.)

I have a couple of ideas how to do both in a somewhat DIY way, but I really think there is probably something "standard" for this task. I will keep trying (next are: try to detect the period from the autocorrelation of the signal with somehow "normalized" peaks for question 1; subtracting a running median taken over ..., x-2T, x-T, x, x+T, x+2T, ... for question 2), but then again maybe you will guide me in a more appropriate direction.

Thank you in advance.

**Background, in case anybody would be interested:** the signals are spectra coming from a mass-spectrometer. The nature of the periodic signal is not fully clear, there is a suspicion that these might come from interference of different "packets" that are too weak per se to be detected (https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets/CMD/posters/po-65557-picket-fence-complexity-ms-spectra-protein-ions-asms2019-po65557-en.pdf). I am interested in removing it in a way agnostic of its nature.